# Can 23/76 wire handle 12V 6A power? I have looked at several tables but cannot find answer

Tags: power, cables, wire

There is nowhere which concretely tells me if 23/76 is sufficient for 12 V 6 amps power. Is it okay to use 23/76 wire for 12 V 6 A?

Comment: Post a link which gives the area of 23/76 wire in proper engineering units, preferrably metric. We can tell you how much heat it will generate while carrying 6 A. But we don't know the thermal environment you're going to use the wire in, or the maximum service temperature of the insulation, both of which will affect whether the wire will handle it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the "23/76" notation denotes wire that has 23 strands of 0.0076 inch (7.6 mils) diameter wire. The total area would be about .673 mm^2, which is roughly equivalent to AWG 19. To me, 6 A of current would be rather a lot for this size of wire, except maybe for very short runs. The resistance would be 25 mOhm/meter, which gives you 900 mW/meter dissipation and 150 mV/meter voltage drop.

Comment: I do not want energy dissipation, I just wanted to know if its a standard spec wire whose rating is already specified, because I for one could not find any specification that tells current rating. But the one answer helped it out.

Comment: What do you think a wire's "rating" is based on? Temperature rise is a direct function of power dissipation. But in some applications, voltage drop becomes the critical parameter. You specified nothing about your requirements other than the nominal current.